# Expanding Binomial using Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a general expression for the Laurent Series expansion of

$f(z) = (z-\alpha)^{-n}$

when $|z|>|\alpha|$.

I've tried expanding the function using the binomial theorem, and I've tried
integrating with the general formula for Laurent Series coefficients 
using Cauchy's Integral formula, but I can't get the solution,
which I know is supposed to be

$\Sigma_{j=n}^{\infty} \alpha^{j-n} \frac{(j-1)!}{(n-1)!(j-n)!}z^{-j}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(z-\alpha)^{-n} = \frac1{z^n} \left(1-\frac\alpha z\right)^{-n}.$$

Now expand the (...) term using the [generalized binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem).